# How to createAssociatedTokenAccount for PDA?

Tags: spl-token

Currently, I face into the `TokenOwnerOffCurveError` error trying to call `createAccount` from `@solana/spl-token`, what with `createAssociatedTokenAccount` being invoked under the hood which, in turn, calls `getAssociatedTokenAddress` which tests whether it `isOnCurve`. To be precise, there is the function in question:

```
export async function getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    mint: PublicKey,
    owner: PublicKey,
    allowOwnerOffCurve = false,
    programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    associatedTokenProgramId = ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
): Promise<PublicKey> {
    if (!allowOwnerOffCurve && !PublicKey.isOnCurve(owner.toBuffer())) throw new TokenOwnerOffCurveError();

    const [address] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [owner.toBuffer(), programId.toBuffer(), mint.toBuffer()],
        associatedTokenProgramId
    );

    return address;
}
```

to go up the frame-stack:

```
export async function createAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection: Connection,
    payer: Signer,
    mint: PublicKey,
    owner: PublicKey,
    confirmOptions?: ConfirmOptions,
    programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    associatedTokenProgramId = ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
): Promise<PublicKey> {
    const associatedToken = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint, owner, false, programId, associatedTokenProgramId);

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
        createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
            payer.publicKey,
            associatedToken,
            owner,
            mint,
            programId,
            associatedTokenProgramId
        )
    );

    await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer], confirmOptions);

    return associatedToken;
}
```

as you can see, there is no option to make `createAssociatedTokenAccount` to pass anything except `false` to the `allowOwnerOffCurve` parameter.

SO I wonder: How am I supposed to create a TokenAssociatedAccount controlled by a program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of `@solana/spl-token` version `0.2.0` and above, you can use the [getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/src/actions/getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.ts#L35)

It passes the param `allowOwnerOffCurve` to the `getAssociatedTokenAddress` function.

```
/**
 * Retrieve the associated token account, or create it if it doesn't exist
 *
 * @param connection               Connection to use
 * @param payer                    Payer of the transaction and initialization fees
 * @param mint                     Mint associated with the account to set or verify
 * @param owner                    Owner of the account to set or verify
 * @param allowOwnerOffCurve       Allow the owner account to be a PDA (Program Derived Address)
 * @param commitment               Desired level of commitment for querying the state
 * @param confirmOptions           Options for confirming the transaction
 * @param programId                SPL Token program account
 * @param associatedTokenProgramId SPL Associated Token program account
 *
 * @return Address of the new associated token account
 */
export async function getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection: Connection,
    payer: Signer,
    mint: PublicKey,
    owner: PublicKey,
    allowOwnerOffCurve = false,
    commitment?: Commitment,
    confirmOptions?: ConfirmOptions,
    programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    associatedTokenProgramId = ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
): Promise<Account> {
    const associatedToken = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        mint,
        owner,
        allowOwnerOffCurve,
        programId,
        associatedTokenProgramId
    );
```